# How to insert character varying array into postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql

I want to insert a json array into postgresql?This is my code:

```
def post(self,request):
    request_data = '''
      {
        "name":"a",
        "isbn":"dd",
        "author":["a","b"],
        "publisher":["a","b"],
        "price":"ddd"}
    '''
    data = json.loads(request_data)
    serializer = BookSerializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

And this is my field define:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.Serializer):                
    name = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True, max_length=100)
    isbn = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True, max_length=100)
    author = serializers.ListField(required=False)
    publisher = serializers.ListField(required=False, max_length=100)
    price = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True, max_length=100)
```

And the book define in the model is:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, default='')
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=16,blank=False)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=16,blank=False)
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=16,blank=False)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=16,blank=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'book'
```

When I am request the function,the error stack output like this:

```
 malformed array literal: "['a', 'b']"
LINE 1: ...author", "publisher", "price") VALUES ('a', 'dd', '[''a'', '...
                                                             ^
DETAIL:  "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/spider/api/book
Django Version: 2.1.3
Exception Type: DataError
Exception Value:    
malformed array literal: "['a', 'b']"
LINE 1: ...author", "publisher", "price") VALUES ('a', 'dd', '[''a'', '...
                                                             ^
DETAIL:  "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute, line 85
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.7.1
Python Path:    
['/Users/dolphin/source/pydolphin',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/dolphin/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 25 Nov 2018 15:42:19 +0000
```

How to avoid this problem?

Comment: '[''a'', 

The error is pointing at this part and you have two single quotes (') rather than (") which looks wrong to me. Something in your library code is trying to put single quotes around array values which is wrong compared to your source data. Also, PostgreSQL arrays aren't bracketed with "[]" but with "{}"

Comment: Why are you trying to add a Book in your get method? That is not how REST APIs are supposed to work.

Comment: @RedCricket I know,I'll change it to pot when the demo run success

Comment: How are `author` and `publisher` fields defined in the model?

Comment: @RomanKonoval Thanks for your remind,I tweak the field define of model and it works

Answer (score 0):

Just tweak the array model define like this:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, default='')
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=16,blank=False)
    author = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200))
    publisher = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=16,blank=False))
    price = models.CharField(max_length=16,blank=False)
```

don't forget to import reference:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db.models import FileField
```